# Combine two arrays into a hashtable

Tags: arrays, loops, powershell, nested, hashtable

Is there a way to combine two arrays to a hashtable ?

```
$Name = Get-ChildItem C:\Users | Select-Object Name
$CreationTime = Get-ChildItem C:\Users | Select-Object CreationTime

$Table = New-Object psobject

foreach ($item in $Name) {
    foreach ($item2 in $CreationTime) {

    Add-Member -InputObject $Table -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $item -Value $item2 } }
```

If I simply print out $item and $item2 I get every result multiple times, I know that this is because of the nested foreachs.

The example above is not very good, i acutally would need this to import different csv files and create a hashtable to export them again.

Comment: Why are you not just using `Get-ChildItem C:\Users | Select-Object Name,CreationTime`? Or is that why you mean by this is a bad example. It might be better to show us what you are actually doing.

Comment: Yes, like I said at the bottom, I want to combine two csv files to a single hashtable.

Comment: Do the two file share a common key or can they be combined line for line?

Comment: No common key. I have another script that combines two csv files that share a common key, in this case the nested foreach solution works.

Comment: Do you actually want a hashtable, or an array of custom objects? Are the CSVs ordered in such a way that record 1 of one CSV is associated with record 1 of the other?

Comment: Either one is fine. I'm searching for a general good practice way to combine two arrays, assuming they have the same length and the data is exported in right order.

Answer (score 2):

Have a single for loop were you iterate through the first array with an index. Assuming the same index in both arrays gives the correct pair, add the pair to the hashtable. No need for nested loops.

Some Pseudo code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $Name.length; $i++) {
    Add-Member -Name $Name[$i] -Value $CreationTime[$i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I requested would look something like this:

```
$Name = Get-ChildItem C:\Users | Select-Object Name
$CreationTime = Get-ChildItem C:\Users | Select-Object CreationTime
$Table = New-Object psobject
$i = 0

do {

Add-Member -InputObject $Table -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $Name[$i].Name -Value $CreationTime[$i].CreationTime

$i++ }
while ($i -ne $name.Length)

$Table
```

However, this solution is more like what I wanted:

```
$Name = Get-ChildItem C:\Users | Select-Object Name
$CreationTime = Get-ChildItem C:\Users | Select-Object CreationTime
$TableData =@()
$i = 0

do {

$Table = New-Object psobject

Add-Member -InputObject $Table -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FolderName:" -Value $Name.Name[$i]
Add-Member -InputObject $Table -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Creation Time:" -Value     $CreationTime.CreationTime[$i]

$TableData += $Table

$i++ }
while ($i -ne $name.Length)

$TableData | Export-csv -Delimiter ";" -Path $PSScriptRoot\out.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Sorry for being unspecific! Is there an easier way to do this ?